# How to transfer data from JSP to servlet with upload function?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload

I have a JSP page with an HTML form:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="UploadServlet" name="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

            Select file to upload: <input type="file" name="uploadFile" >
            <input type="text" name="fileNames" > 
        <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="652973" > 
            <br/><br/> 
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

        </form>
```

web.xml

```
<display-name>UploadServletApp</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>UploadServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>net.code.upload.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UploadServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

UploadServlet.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    factory.setSizeThreshold(THRESHOLD_SIZE);
    String paths="C:\\Uploaded_FIle\\";
    factory.setRepository(new File(paths));

    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
    upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);

    // constructs the directory path to store upload file
    //String uploadPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("")+ File.separator + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;
    String uploadPath =paths+File.separator + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;
    // creates the directory if it does not exist
    File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath);
    if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
        uploadDir.mkdir();
    }
try {

            // parses the request's content to extract file data
            List formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iter = formItems.iterator();

            // iterates over form's fields
            while ( iter.hasNext () ) 
             {
                FileItem fi = (FileItem)iter.next();
                if ( !fi.isFormField () )  {
                    String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
                    String fileName = fi.getName();
                    boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
                    long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
                    File file = new File( uploadDir + "yourFileName") ;
                    fi.write( file ) ;
                     }
             }

            request.setAttribute("message", "Upload has been done successfully!\n"  + uploadDir  + "<br>");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            request.setAttribute("message", "There was an error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
```

The problem is, I am able to upload the file, but the values which I'm sending are not coming, like fileNames,form_id. I am not getting any values which entered through jsp page as well as hard-coded values.

Comment: Have you used @MultipartConfig on the class?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet `if ( !fi.isFormField () )` in your code skips the fields which you are sending and only processes the files that are sent. So to get the fields you need to handle both the cases:

1. When the field is a form field like radio-button, text, etc.
2. When the field is a file.

This should give you an idea.

```
 try {
    List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
    for (FileItem item : items) {
        if (item.isFormField()) {
            // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
            String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
            String fieldValue = item.getString();
            // ... (do your job here)
        } else {
            // Process form file field (input type="file").
            String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
            String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
            InputStream fileContent = item.getInputStream();
            // ... (do your job here)
        }
    }
} catch (FileUploadException e) {
    throw new ServletException("Cannot parse multipart request.", e);
}
```